# How to extract content from a repeating pattern of text?

Tags: javascript, regex

The text is a custom serialized form of an array of patient records.

```
<PATIENTID>=1231
<PATIENTNAME>=ERICA
<PATIENTHISTORY>=MULTILINE TEXT
<KEYPOINTS>= ASTHMA, HBP, DIABETES
<PATIENTID>=1232
<PATIENTNAME>=NELSON
<PATIENTHISTORY>=MULTILINE TEXT
<KEYPOINTS>= JAUNDICE
```

I tried to extract it with the following regex, but it matches the entire string instead of each record.

```
const regEx= /^<PATIENTID>=(.)+<PATIENTNAME>=(.)+<PATIENTHISTORY>=(.)+<KEYPOINTS>=(.)+/g;
```

So how should I alter the regex to iterate over each record and extract the relevant fields?

Comment: What is the final result you want to obtain?

Comment: Deserialize the entire text to object array format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could seach for left angle and the content between right angle and the rest until a not right angle is found then take key and value pairs.

Playground: https://regex101.com/r/sf5soM/1

```js
var string = '<PATIENTID>=1231\n<PATIENTNAME>=ERICA\n<PATIENTHISTORY>=MULTILINE TEXT\n<KEYPOINTS>= ASTHMA, HBP, DIABETES\n<PATIENTID>=1232\n<PATIENTNAME>=NELSON\n<PATIENTHISTORY>=MULTILINE TEXT\n<KEYPOINTS>= JAUNDICE',
    regex = /<([^>]*)>=([^<]*)/gm,
    m,
    k, v;
    result = [];

while ((m = regex.exec(string)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    [, k, v] = m;

    if (k === 'PATIENTID') {
        result.push({});
    }
    result[result.length - 1][k] = v.trim();
}
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: With `([^<]*)`, the pattern will not match values with `<` in them.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, i do not know, how to separate multiline from single line feed. the left angle should be safer, if all data has encoded angles.

Answer (score 0):

you can just substring for each of the data.

```
var str = "<PATIENTID>=1231";
var afterComma = str.substr(str.indexOf("=") + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/^<PATIENTID>=([\s\S]*?)<PATIENTNAME>=([\s\S]*?)<PATIENTHISTORY>=([\s\S]*?)<KEYPOINTS>=([\s\S]*?)(?=<PATIENTID>|$)/gm
```

https://regex101.com/r/DpSD1R/4

The main thing here is the `(?:\s|\S)` group which make sure that you match space and non space characters... which means everything. The difference with `.` (dot) is that it will even match line feeds, and you'll need it as some of your fields are multiline.

Edit: simplified non capturing group (`(?:\s|\S)`) with `[\s\S]` as fully fledged alternatives are not strictly needed here.

Edit 2: As @Wiktor pointed out, the match should end either at the end of the input or at the start of another record. Added a terminal condition with a positive lookahead `(?=<PATIENTID>|$)`, also forgot the multiline flag

Comment: Please use appropriate constructs to match any symbol, `[^]*` or `[\s\S]*`. Do not use `(?:\s|\S)*?`. In ECMAScript 2018, you can already use `.` with `s` modifier.

Comment: It does not match two blocks correctly. See https://regex101.com/r/OJVKZx/1

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew : ES2018 is still far away, if you wan't to write softwares that work now that's how you do it. Besides regex come in lot of flavours, and there will always be some which does not implements dotall. Knowing about the \s\S trick is useful and will continue to be in the foreseeable future

Comment: Do you know a single flavor that has no DOTALL for regex? I know, it is ElasticSearch, Lucene engine. All others support it, either by default, as TRE or POSIX, or with modifiers (`s` or `m`).

Comment: "It does not match two blocks correctly" : Which blocks ? I don't see any issue.

Comment: Then I suggest that you have a look at the input data. There are two blocks in it. And OP says there are more.

Comment: Thanks I didn't noticed there was multiple records in the input. Just updated the response

Comment: You need `m` modifier to make `$` match end of the line.

Answer (score 0):

You could capture the name bewtween the angle brackets in a group `^<([^>]+)>`, then match an equals sign `=` and for the second part match all characters until you encounter the angle bracket pattern on the next line as that is the start of a new match.

This way you can also match `<>` in the MULTILINE TEXT part.

[`<([^>]+)>=([\s\S]*?(?=^<[^[\r\n>]+>)|[\s\S]*)`](https://regex101.com/r/emfwVA/1)

Explanation

- `<([^>]+)>` Capture what is between the angle brackets in a group (capturing group 1)
- `=` Match literally
- `([\s\S]*?` Match all characters zero or more times non greedy
- `(?=^<[^[\r\n>]+>)` Positive lookahead that asserts what follows is the angle bracket pattern at the start of the line
- `|` or
- `[\s\S]*` Match all characters (You could replace this to `.*` to only match the whole last line instead of match all characters)

```js
const regex = /<([^>]+)>=([\s\S]*?(?=^<[^[\r\n>]+>)|[\s\S]*)/gm;
const str = `<PATIENTID>=1231
<PATIENTNAME>=ERICA
<PATIENTHISTORY>=MULTILINE TEXT
< with a line
with a line >
with a <> line
<> with a line
<KEYPOINTS>= ASTHMA, HBP, DIABETES
<PATIENTID>=1232
<PATIENTNAME>=NELSON
<PATIENTHISTORY>=MULTILINE TEXT
and this is a line
and this also
<KEYPOINTS>= JAUNDICE
and this is a line`;
let m, result = [];
while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
    regex.lastIndex++;
  }
  if (m[1] === 'PATIENTID') {
    result.push({});
  }
  result[result.length - 1][m[1]] = m[2];
}
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my idea, you can use some other functionality and get the expected results.
Hope this helps...

```
const text = `
  <PATIENTID>=1231
  <PATIENTNAME>=ERICA
  <PATIENTHISTORY>=MULTILINE TEXT
  <KEYPOINTS>= ASTHMA, HBP, DIABETES
  <PATIENTID>=1232
  <PATIENTNAME>=NELSON
  <PATIENTHISTORY>=MULTILINE TEXT
  <KEYPOINTS>= JAUNDICE
`;

const test = text.replace(/<PATIENT/g, ';').replace(/>=/g, ':').replace(/<KEYPOINTS/g, 'KEYPOINTS').split(';');
const ObjectList = [];

test.map((t) => {
  const text = t.trim();
  const finalText = text.replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, ';').split(';').map(a => a.trim());
  if(finalText) {
    finalText.forEach(item => item && ObjectList.push(item));
  }
});

console.log(ObjectList);

// output: ["ID:1231",
            "NAME:ERICA",
            "HISTORY:MULTILINE TEXT",
            "KEYPOINTS: ASTHMA, HBP, DIABETES",
            "ID:1232",
            "NAME:NELSON",
            "HISTORY:MULTILINE TEXT",
            "KEYPOINTS: JAUNDICE"
            ]
```